# Negative Margin in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, margin

I'm having a rather strange issue with a site I'm working on. It involves a "ribbon" navigation, with a folded corner on each end wrapping behind the container. On the left, the negative margin on the ribbon corner works just fine. On the right, however, the ribbon absolutely refuses to go outside the wrapper in IE. I can use negative `margin` up to `-18px`, but it needs to be `-38px`. If I set it to `-1000px` it still behaves as though it's at `-18px`. This happens in IE7, IE8 and IE9. I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: im looking at it in ie9 and it looks fine...

Comment: Just to add, this works fine in IE8 and IE9 (when viewed using the developer tool in IE9). There is a potential fix in that you could float it to the left instead, and give it a large margin-left around 950px for IE7 browsers, though there may be a more plausible fix instead.

Comment: Tried adding padding, did nothing. That float thing's an idea, though, at least for the navigation. Problem is that there's also internal sidebars with ribbons, so having however much margin-left wouldn't work great there.

Comment: if you don't get it fixed in ie7 you can always add the wrap-around parts of the ribbon to the background image since it is centered with the main container

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to [validate your html](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fplayqcr.weblinx.us%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) prior to troubleshooting any rendering issues in IE.  Explorer _hates_ invalid HTML even more than valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this issue only in IE7.

I'd wrap `<ul id="nav">` into a `<div>`, set it to `position: relative; padding-bottom: 20px` and absolutely position the ribbon corners to `bottom:0; left:0` and `right:0` respectively.